# Upload, create, share google spreadsheet

Tags: android

I want to make an application that can upload a spreadsheet and can be shared with other Google accounts.
I also want that spreadsheet can be modified through the application.
Apart from Google's spreadsheet API, what other API are needed for this purpose.
Thanks in advance!!